# Intellij pom.xml dependency could not be resolved

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

My project is unable to resolve the com.twitter:hbc-core:2.2.0 dependency.  You can see the pom.xml file below. I've tried reimporting all Maven projects, and I see that the dependency is in the repository at https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.twitter/hbc-core/2.2.0/jar .  The central repository used is https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 .  The classes are not able to be imported, and alt + enter does not offer a meaningful import.

Minimal, complete, verifiable example:

```
import com.twitter.hbc.core.endpoint.StatusesFilterEndpoint;

public class TwitterProducer {


    public static  void main(String[] args){
        StatusesFilterEndpoint hosebirdEndpoint = new StatusesFilterEndpoint();
    }
}
```

What might I be missing here?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.github.simplestep</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-beginners-course</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.twitter</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbc-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Does the project build from the command line?

Comment: @CrazyCoder : no, it does not at I have references to classes provided by the dependency.  Sample:  Error:(25, 9) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Hosts
  location: class com.github.simplestep.tutorial2.TwitterProducer

Comment: In this case the issue has no relation to IntelliJ IDEA. Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Done, question updated with Minimal Complete and Verifiable example.

Comment: The import statements are missing from your Java code making this example incomplete.

Comment: `import com.twitter.hbc.core.endpoint.StatusesFilterEndpoint.java;` is not valid.

Comment: I just updated it; you responded too quickly :)  It doesn't matter; even if I add the import statement it tells me that it cannot resolve symbol twitter.

Comment: The issue is [not reproducible](https://i.imgur.com/YHKnILX.png) using the provided information. The code compiles from the IDE and from the command line Maven. What is the specific error you get when building it from Maven?

Comment: Errors follow:  Error:(4, 37) java: package com.twitter.hbc.core.endpoint does not exist
Error:(8, 9) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class StatusesFilterEndpoint
  location: class com.github.simplestep.tutorial2.TwitterProducer
Error:(8, 55) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class StatusesFilterEndpoint
  location: class com.github.simplestep.tutorial2.TwitterProducer

Comment: Do you see the dependencies present in the module like shown on my screenshot? Do you have any proxy? Is Maven able to download the dependencies? Does it help if you delete .m2 directory in your home and let Maven download the jars again?

Comment: Interesting.  I did see the complete path in the .m2 folder, and so I renamed it m2.old, restarted Intellij, and then reimported all project and voilà!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the communication in the comments, it appears that some dependencies downloaded by Maven into the local `.m2` folder were corrupted.

Forcing Maven to download them again by removing/renaming this folder has solved the problem.